# New in Qt getting Linker and Makefile errors

Tags: c++, qt

I want to run and compile some `Qt` code so I can learn it , I went to the website below and I saw they provided some `Qt` examples

[Sample Qt Code](http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/widgets-analogclock.html)

I use the latest version, then I copied the code but I get these errors :

> mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2005: main already defined in main.obj
>
> debug\uwm.exe:-1: error: LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols
> found

**So I asked my question in '[qt forum](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27223/)' , They suggested to delete "mainwindow.h" and "mainwindow.cpp" from directory of my project**

If I do so, the first errors are gone but after I build the project I get new ones :

> 11:58:21: Running steps for project uwm... 11:58:21: Configuration
> unchanged, skipping qmake step. 11:58:21: Starting:
> "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"
> C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug Error:
> dependent '..\uwm\mainwindow.cpp' does not exist. jom:
> D:\qt\build-uwm-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug]
> Error 2 11:58:21: The process
> "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2. Error
> while building/deploying project uwm (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.2 MSVC2012
> 64bit) When executing step 'Make' 11:58:21: Elapsed time: 00:00.

Comment: I couldn't submit the screen shot of my second error http://s21.postimg.org/6z7t2mnx3/Scrshot11.png

Comment: For some reason after you changed the project `Makefile` and `Makefile.Debug` were not updated. Try deleting the whole `D:\qt\build-uwm-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug` and try again.

Comment: @Paul Thanks man SOLVED !!! Perfect ... you are right Makefile and Makefile.Debug were not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you change your code after making or trying to build a code written and compiled on another machine the best way to avoid such problems and have a .pro file taylored for your working environment is to run a make clean, then run qmake -project again and then building it.

```
$ make clean
$ qmake -project
$ qmake [your .pro file name here].pro
$ make
```

but you should note that qmake does not insert all the parameters you need to generate a proper MakeFile in your .pro file. for example if you have used external libraries such as boost you need to add them manually using `LIBS +=` in your `.pro` file. it's better to use "Qt Creator" so you don't have to do this everytime you want to build your code and that involves a correct .pro file and configuration as explained. also pay good attention to your compiler errors and try to resolve the issues one by one until you successsfully build your code.